# eclipse Oxygen mouse hover not showing error/warnings

Tags: java, hover, eclipse-oxygen

After upgrading to new eclipse Oxygen (4.7.0), I don't see code warnings or errors when I hover on the highlighted code element.
Also, I can't get variable values in debug mode when hovering on one.

For both cases, javadoc is being show.

I tried to reset hover preferences under Java and general section to its defaults, but it does not fix the problem.

Is there any workaround/fix for this, or as usual, we have to wait for the next  eclipse service release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question, to help anyone with the same issue.

After reporting this to [eclipse Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=519559), I got a comment about possibility of conflict with an updated plugin. I then checked my newly installed plugins and found the guilty one: [ZipEditor](http://zipeditor.sourceforge.net/update) v1.1.3.201703012047

Deleting this plugin fixed my issue.

EDIT: It looks like the issue was layered and I had to remove eclipse Class Decompiler 2.9.11.20170710, too.

Comment: Thanks for your investigation! This issue was really annoying! For me it was caused by Eclipse Class Decompiler. With the new release ``2.9.14.20170714`` it works, again.

Comment: Yes, the new release is fine. Thanks to the plugin developers.